# Unable to transfer files from Windows to Linux via Bluetooth using 32feet.Net C# library

Tags: c#, windows, linux, bluetooth

First linux service listening process is started using the following command:

*obexpushd –B[00:15:83:3D:0A:57]:9 –d –o /home/myfolder*

On windows the following code is used to perform the obex transfer:

```
InTheHand.Net.BluetoothAddress address = peerDevice.DeviceAddress;
   System.Uri uri = new Uri("obex://" + address.ToString() + "/" + srcfile.Name);
   request = new ObexWebRequest(uri);
   startcopy = DateTime.Now;

   request.ReadFile(file); // this performs the file read from the hard drive

   try
   {
       response = (ObexWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // here file should be pushed to the listening service
   }
   catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
   {
       if (response != null) {
                            response.Close();
       }
       return;
   }
```

Devices see each other and their obex services are visible as well.
Transfer seems to be successful, but no data is actually transferred.
The code works between windows and windows without a problem.

Obexpushd process ouput shows:

```
obexpushd 0.10.2 Copyright (C) 2006-2010 Hendrik Sattler
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions.
Listening on bluetooth/[00:15:83:3D:0A:57]:9
OBEX_EV_ACCEPTHINT, OBEX_CMD_CONNECT
0: Connection from "bluetooth/[00:09:DD:50:94:0B]:9"
0: OBEX_EV_REQHINT, OBEX_CMD_CONNECT
0: OBEX_EV_REQ, OBEX_CMD_CONNECT
0: Sending response code 0
0: OBEX_EV_REQDONE, OBEX_CMD_CONNECT
0: OBEX_EV_REQHINT, OBEX_CMD_PUT
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQCHECK, OBEX_CMD_PUT
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQDONE, OBEX_CMD_PUT
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQHINT, OBEX_CMD_DISCONNECT
0.1: Sending response code 100
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQ, OBEX_CMD_DISCONNECT
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQDONE, OBEX_CMD_DISCONNECT
```

I have also tried to disable Authentication in C# code but that did not help.

Does any one have idea how to nail this problem down or where to even start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it seems that no one is much interested in this topic. :) Fortunately I have found the solution myself.

However, it involved a lot of analysis (of both obex transfer protocol and 32feet library) and a bit of luck.
The difference between Linux *obexpushd* implementation lies in its interpretation of OBEX transfer packets.

I found the OBEX specification on page: [OBEX specification](http://netwinder.osuosl.org/pub/netwinder/docs/nw/irda/IrOBEX12.pdf).

After debugging the internals of the 23feet obex transfer I found where the code sends the OBEX PUT command used to send file to the receiver. Obex specification gives the following example for PUT inititialization packet:

PUT Command | length of packet | Name header  | Length of Name header | name of object | Length header | Length of object | Object Body chunk header | Length of Body header | bytes of body

The 32feet library sends the first packet **without** the **Body Header** which causes error in *obexpushd* Linux command.

Not shure if it is error in 32feet library, obexpushd or if the OBEX specification is not precise enough, but adding the Body header to the first packet solved the problem. From my experiments it turns out that at least 2 first bytes of the objectt must be sent in the first packet. Moreover, adding the header does not crash anything else and Windows<->Windows transfer still works very well.

Comment: I'm maintainer of 32feet.NET and missed the question. I'm glad you solved it.

The OBEX spec specifically allows the first PUT packet to not include Body, presumably so to not waste bandwidth if the filename is not allowed etc. From OBEX13.pdf section 3.3.3:  "The implementer may choose whether to include an object Body header in the initial packet, or wait until the response to a subsequent packet is received before sending any object body chunks."

So obexpushd would seem wrong here…

Comment: Yes, it seems so. I was not sure which side was wrong as didn't have so much time to look into the details. Thanks for quick reaction and response. Perhaps I will let know to someone who is maintainig linux obex tools about this issue.